# Runtime type checking in Dart - Check for List

Tags: dart, dynamic, types, instanceof

I want to check if the response of a `http` request matches a specific `datatype` (= `List<dynamic`).

```
case 200:
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    print(responseJson['results'].runtimeType);  // Output: I/flutter (13862): List<dynamic>
    print(responseJson['results'].runtimeType is List<dynamic>);  // Output: I/flutter (13862): false

    if (responseJson['results'].runtimeType is List<dynamic> &&
        responseJson['results'].length > 0) {
      return responseJson;
    }
    throw NotFoundException('Result is empty...');
```

I'm confused... why does it print `false`? The ouput of `runtimType` shows `List<dynamic>`so it should be `true`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only use `runtimeType` for debug purposes since this property returns the actual type of the object on runtime and cannot be used for checking if a given type is compatible with another type.

The `is` operator is the correct operator you are using for checking the type but you are using it against `runtimeType` which returns a `Type` object. Instead you should just use it like: `responseJson['results'] is List<dynamic>`.

This will check if the type is compatible with `List<dynamic>`. You could also do it like this which is a little simpler: `responseJson['results'] is List`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have to search other occurrences of `runtimeType` in my `flutter` project and change them as well :D